# Using ::find but with a custom where clause

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I use `::find` to find the business but business_position I need to use WHERE `business_id` = and WHERE `id` to find the correct position, and example is avalible below...

```
<?php
    $s = Stats::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $myJob = \App\Businesses::find($s->business_id);

    $matchedValues = ['business_id' => $s->business_id, 'id' => $s->business_position];
    $myPosition = \App\BusinessPositions::where($matchedValues)->get();
    ?>
```

And using `$myPosition` I use

```
{{ $myPosition->pay_amount }}
```

And on that line it throws and error...

> Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$pay_amount (View:
>   C:\Users\Darren\MyLavProject\resources\views\pages\business\business.blade.php)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's `get()` returns a **collection** of results that match your query (even if there are none or just one, it'll be an array of Laravel model instances).

You can use `first()` instead of `get()` to grab the first result, or you can `foreach` through each of the results `get()` provides. It depends if your application permits more than one permission per `business_id`/`id` combination.

Comment: are you sure it's possible to use an associative array inside `where` clause?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin `>>> App\User::where(['test' => 'testing', 'test2' => 'testing2'])->toSql()
=> "select * from "users" where ("test" = ? and "test2" = ?)"` on my Tinker.

Comment: May want to mention that you can continue to use `find()`, as well: `$myPosition = \App\BusinessPositions::where('business_id', $s->business_id)->find($s->business_position);`. `find()` is just a shortcut for `where('id', $id)->first()`.

Answer (score 0):

`$myPosition` This is an array of objects.

So if you need the result:

```
{{ $myPosition[0]->pay_amount }}
```

Or

```
@foreach($myPosition as $position)
  {{ $position->pay_amout }}
@endforeach
```

Of if you don't want to use any of these:

Change your query to :

```
$myPosition = \App\BusinessPositions::where($matchedValues)->first();
```

Now you can use: `{{ $myPosition->pay_amount }}`